# How can I show a flash notice message when I get PG::ForeignKeyViolation error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 2 models, Bidding and BiddingItem.

```
class Bidding < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bidding_items, dependent: :restrict_with_error
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :bidding_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class BiddingItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :bidding
end
```

By adding the following dependency to the Bidding model, I get no errors, but I'd still like to show a message to the user.

```
has_many :bidding_items, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

How could I show a flash notice message to the user instead of getting this error view or getting no errors at all (by using the dependency I mentioned before)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`ActiveSupport#rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) in your `biddings_controller` and pass a defined private method in the `with` options, to "raise" everytime such error occurrs in that controller.

As you can define any logic in the method being used, then you can redirect to the same biddings_path and pass a custom message within the `notice` flash, like:

```
class BiddingsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey, with: :invalid_foreign_key

  private

  def invalid_foreign_key
    redirect_to biddings_path, notice: 'Some custom message.'
  end
end
```

You just need to be sure to be rendering the `notice` within the current view.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to delete bidding, and there's a bidding_item entry which points to what you want to delete, correct?

I think you should add a callback, `before_delete`, check there for such condition and add an error.

You could also use `:nullify` flag if you're ok with the situation that this `bidding_item` will have the value nullified when you delete `bidding`